# SQL Pivot table with one column

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot

I am sure this has been answered before but I just can't work this out. I am trying to pivot a table that I have split up from a list its starts as 'A+A+2,B+B+1' ect then split the list into a table of 
A+A+2
B+B+1 ect

Then I split it to a table of -

A|

A|

2|

I then want to pivot the table to be A | A | 2

The problem I'm having is the aggregating part of the pivot you seem to need some type of count, sum so on but I cant work out what I should put as the #tempSplit2 table only has items in it.

Any help would be great!

Thanks

```
SELECT [section], [letter], [number]
    FROM
        (SELECT items
            FROM #tempSplit2) AS SourceTable
    PIVOT
    (
        COUNT(items) --*This is wrong*
        FOR items IN ([section], [letter], [number])
    ) AS PivotTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

MAX() works for all data types, and if you know there can be no duplicates in your input you can be certain there will be no data loss.